# UtteranceProgressListener Out of Sync

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Summary

- List of utterances in an array
- Loop through array and call my method "sayThis" for each utterance
- UtteranceProgressListener is being called, and TTS works
- Calling of my method "sayThis" appears to be called at times prior to UtteranceProgressListener completing current utterance

I believe the flow should be the following:

1) Call to method "sayThis", if voiceReady=true 
2) TTS starts utterance and UtteranceProgressListener onStart called & sets voiceReady to false
3) Call to method "sayThis" should not be called if voiceReady=false
4) UtteranceProgressListener onDone called when utterance if finished, voiceReady=true
5) Call to method "sayThis" can be called again, since voiceReady=true
6) Above should continue until utterance array had been looped through to completion

```
    //Code snippet that loops through array and calls "sayThis" method
    //There are no errors
    while(arrayCounter < utterances.size()) {
        if (voice.voiceReady == true) {
            voice.sayThis(utterances.get(arrayCounter), arrayCounter);
            arrayCounter++;
        }
    }

    //Code snippet that processes speech
    //There are no errors
    public void sayThis(String whatToSay, int utteranceID){
    Log.d(LOG_SOURCE, "sayThis method called: Utterance ID=" + utteranceID);
    voiceParams.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, Integer.toString(utteranceID));
    ttsVoice.speak(whatToSay, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, voiceParams);        
}

    //Code snippet from the UtteranceProgressListener
    //You can see from the logs the methods are being called
    @Override
    public void onStart(String utteranceID) {
        voiceReady = false;
        Log.d(LOG_SOURCE, "(ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart " +
                "method called for utteranceID:" + utteranceID + ", voiceReady=false");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDone(String utteranceID) {
        voiceReady = true;
        Log.d(LOG_SOURCE, "(ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone " +
                "method called for utteranceID:" + utteranceID + ", voiceReady=true");
```

- Logcat would indicate this pattern isn't always followed as shown below:

```
02-13 18:05:25.487: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=0
02-13 18:05:25.490: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:0, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:29.578: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:0, voiceReady=true
02-13 18:05:29.578: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=1
02-13 18:05:29.580: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:1, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:33.107: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=2
02-13 18:05:33.107: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:1, voiceReady=true
02-13 18:05:33.109: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:2, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:38.667: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=3
02-13 18:05:38.667: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:2, voiceReady=true
02-13 18:05:38.668: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=4
02-13 18:05:38.669: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=5
02-13 18:05:38.671: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:3, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:45.411: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:3, voiceReady=true
02-13 18:05:45.411: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:4, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:49.966: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:4, voiceReady=true
02-13 18:05:49.966: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:5, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:54.198: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:5, voiceReady=true
02-13 18:05:54.199: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=6
02-13 18:05:54.202: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:6, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:55.912: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:6, voiceReady=true
02-13 18:05:55.912: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): sayThis method called: Utterance ID=7
02-13 18:05:55.914: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onStart method called for utteranceID:7, voiceReady=false
02-13 18:05:56.765: D/LFS_TheVoice(10645): (ttsUtteranceListener) UtteranceProgressListener onDone method called for utteranceID:7, voiceReady=true
```

Any recommendation on how to sync the flow?  
It's almost like the iteration through the array and calling the "sayThis" method happens faster than the UtteranceProgressListener can keep up with switching the true/false value of "voiceReady" boolean. 
This will cause flow control issues for me if I cannot accurate detect when each utterance has completed.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: TTS is asynchronous and TextToSpeech.speak() doesn't block the UI thread. Your need to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Create class members

```
List<String> mUtterances = new ArrayList<String>();
int mCurrentUtteranceIndex;
```

Save your utterances in `mUtterances` and then call `sayThis(mUtterances.get(0), 0)`

Then `onDone` call the next `sayThis`

```
 @Override
public void onDone(String utteranceID) {
    if (++mCurrentUtteranceIndex < mUtterances.size()) {
        sayThis(mUtterances.get(mCurrentUtteranceIndex), mCurrentUtteranceIndex);
    }
}
```